# Controlling MacMini volume with MacBookPro volume keys?

Tags: sound-volume

I have a MacMini which I use as a server and DVR so it constantly has shows and movies playing on it. I'd like to be able to delegate the volume keys on my MacBookPro to the MacMini and control it's volume from my MBP.

Both devices are always on the same network with static internal IP addresses.

Comment: would Airplay work ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the Airplay for that.

[The models that support Airplay](http://ipadinsight.com/ipad-tips-tricks/how-to-use-airplay-mirroring-from-ipad-to-apple-tv-or-a-mac/)

– If you want to mirror to a Mac: OS X Mountain Lion, a supported Mac, and an app to support mirroring.. Supported Macs are:

```
iMac (Mid 2011 or newer)
Mac mini (Mid 2011 or newer)
MacBook Air (Mid 2011 or newer)
MacBook Pro (Early 2011 or newer)
```

Comment: I will look into it and tell you if I have any success, thanks!

Edit: On second thought, I think you're thinking of an AppleTV. My MacMini is just a server with VLC or Netflix running on it constantly.

Comment: I get that, so where are the media playing on ? screen, tv ...

Comment: On the monitor attached to it.